# Incorrect display when an image is added to XML

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="staff.xsl"?>
<st>        
    <employee>
        <name>
            <firstname>Clay</firstname>
            <lastname>Hansen</lastname>
        </name>

        <jobtitle>Professor</jobtitle>

        <department>Department: Communication and Marketing</department>
        <office>Office: CH-H 111</office>
        <phone>Phone: (847)257-1234</phone>
        <email>Email: clay.h@abc.com</email>
        <profile>
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <img src="C:\Users\username\Desktop\im.jpg" />  <!-- added closing tag by edit -->                                                  
            </html>
        </profile>
    </employee>
</st>
```

[image: the image is a screenshot of my external xslt]
here is my xml and extrenal xsl code. When I add an image, it does not display my data in tabular form. It displays it like words in a sentence. How can I solve it?

Comment: Where is the xslt code?

Comment: Why is the image tag enclosed in its own `html` tag?  The entire `html` element will be selected into the first `td`, which will make the result html invalid.

Comment: I added a closing tag to your `img` tag to make your XML well-formed. Maybe this solves your problem.

Comment: It is still not working with the closing tag. The image is not appearing.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are expecting the line `<xsl:value-of select="profile" />` to display the image? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `xsl:value-of` returns the concatenated text nodes of a element's subtree with the markup removed (in your case there is none). You could copy the `img` node like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="employee">
   <td>
       <xsl:copy-of select="profile//xhtml:img"></xsl:copy-of>
   </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note, that you have to declare the xhtml namespace in your stylesheet to process the `img` nodes:

```
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```